# How to retrieve all users across all domains, and subdomain in a multiple domain Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

We are attempting to retrieve a list of all users in Active Directory (across all domains in a multiple-domain scenario) and within all sub-domains.

We use code similar to the following.

We assumed that our customers could configure their domain with port 3268 (global catalog), and the code would retrieve all users in all domains. The following code does return users, but it is limited to one domain.

Question 1: Why doesn't the Global Catalog contain all users in all domains?

Question 2: Some research has suggested I need to provide a container to search a specific domain.  If that is the case, what value is the Global Catalog when I could just as easily connect to the other domain?

Question 3: Is there a generic way to search all users across all domains?

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    public static class StringMethods
    {
        public static string ValueOrNull(this string source)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) ? null : source;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string server = null;    // domain controller machine name, domain name, or domain:3268 (Global Catalog LDAP) and domain:3269 (Global Catalog LDAPS)
            string container = null; // root of search
            string username = null;  // username to connect to active directory or null for default
            string password = null;  // password of username to connec to to active directory or null for default.

            // attributes to retrieve
            string[] attributes = new string[] { "userPrincipalName", "msds-PrincipalName", "displayName", "distinguishedName", "mail" };

            // change this to your domain
            server = "domain:3268";  // use global catalog
            
            try
            {
                PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
                    ContextType.Domain,
                    server.ValueOrNull(),
                    container.ValueOrNull(),
                    username.ValueOrNull(),
                    password.ValueOrNull());

                using (principalContext)
                {
                    using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext))
                    {
                        using (PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
                        {
                            DirectorySearcher underlyingSearcher = (DirectorySearcher)principalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher();
                            underlyingSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
                            underlyingSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(attributes);
                            underlyingSearcher.SizeLimit = 0;
                            underlyingSearcher.Sort = new SortOption("displayName", SortDirection.Descending);

                            using (SearchResultCollection searchResultCollections = underlyingSearcher.FindAll())
                            {
                                if (searchResultCollections.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResultCollections)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
                                        // Loop over the properties for each user returned.
                                        foreach (string propertyName in searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
                                        {
                                            ResultPropertyValueCollection item = searchResult.Properties[propertyName];
                                            if (item.Count < 1)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(propertyName + " : {null}");
                                            }
                                            else if (item.Count == 1)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(propertyName + " : " + item[0]);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(propertyName + ": ");
                                                foreach (var propertyValue in item)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine(propertyValue.ToString().PadLeft((propertyName + " :").Length));
                                                }
                                            };
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of Global Catalog is that it keeps a record of all other domains in the forest, on this domain's Domain Controller. So if that domain is on another network, you don't need to mess around with VPNs and firewalls, you can just get it off your own DC. Try connecting using `GC://yourdomain`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We know that the Global Catalog keeps a partial replica of information from other domains.  This is why we want to use it.  The code above is accessing "domain:3268" which is supposed to be the global catalog endpoint for a domain. controller.  Our confusion is why the global catalog request to find all the users is only returning users in one domain and not all users across all domains.

When you say try connecting using GC://yourdomain, where do we use that URI?

Comment: I think in the `container` parameter

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added the GC://yourdomain to the container parameter and received an exception:  "Unknown error (0x80005000)".

Comment: Check `underlyingSearcher.SearchRoot` just before you perform the search. I wonder if `PrincipalSearcher` is automatically setting it to the domain. (I prefer to use `DirectorySearcher` directly since it gives you more control of what's going on)